# what is the difference between xyz <- getYieldCurve (year=2019)$df and xyz <- getYieldCurve (year=2019)?

Tags: r

I'm learning R using a manual by Marcelo which is extremely useful but I am struggling to follow some parts.

An example - the topic of this question, I really don't understand what the "$df" does? I tried creating two objects, one with and one without the $df...the tables look the same

[this is the one without the $...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsLKu.png)

and the other one: 
[this is the one with the $...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiPpS.png)

@msperlin

Comment: It looks like `getYieldCurve` returns a list that has several elements. One of these elements is a data frame called `df` (see the `Value` section of the help for `getYieldCurve`). When you type `xyz <- getYieldCurve (year=2019)`, the entire list returned by `getYieldCurve()` is stored in `xyz`. You could then do `xyz$df` to get just the data frame element. Likewise `xyz$month` will provide the `month` element of `xyz`. However, if you type `xyz <- getYieldCurve (year=2019)$df`, then you're only keeping the `df` element of the list returned by `getYieldCurve()`.

Comment: More generally, `$` is one way to extract specific elements of a list or data frame (and a data frame is a special type of list). For example, run `x = list(a=1, b=2, c="AAA"); x; x$a; x$c`. Or, using the built-in `mtcars` data frame, run `mtcars; mtcars$cyl; mtcars$hp`.

Comment: To see the structure of each version of `xyz` you created, run `str(xyz)` after creating each object and look at how the first version differs from the second.

Comment: thank you very much @eipi10. very clear and accurate comment. Running the str(), the getYieldCurve is getting a dataframe plus some tags and using the $df is taking only the dataframe. Thanks again :)